# mysql LIKE = imprecise search

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I'm using a simple query for my search:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%term%'
```

if I have a field = "Company Name 123" and I search for Company 123 the result is null

how can I improve this? it only finds if the term is in sequence

Comment: You should read about full text search in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a % between Company and 123 in order for it to match. You might want to check out full text search functions.

Answer (score 2):

Replace spaces with %

```
$newTerm = str_replace(' ', '%', $term);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%$term%'"

$r = mysql_qery($sql, $conn);
```

Comment: not the problem here, you should read the question first (but you're right, the code in the question won't work, but i'm sure thats just a typo). **EDIT:** brain_damage has corrected the code in the question

Comment: he edited the question since i posted the first time, ive changed it

Comment: I would prefer a `concat('%', $term, '%')` (check what PHP syntax would be here) to be sure not to suffer from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace spaces 
`$searchtext =str_replace(' ','%',$searchtext);`

Answer (score 0):

you could:

- split your searchterm into words and build a query with a lot of ANDs (or ORs if you just want to find one of the parts) out of it (ugly, but i've seen this a lot of times)
- replace ' '(space) with % (thats a wildcard) in your term (the way to go)